# ExtJS4 add attribute to node and refresh the grid

Tags: tree, extjs4, nodes, reload

I have been working with a Ext.tree.Panel which contains basic data of a tree, here I attach an image on how it looks like.

[image]

I have the following Structure: RMTEST(parent), 001(child) and finally the little grandchildren with no label.

The problem I am facing is that the other columns: **Billable, After Hours, Cust App Busn Hrs and Cust App After Hrs** requires data from the child (001) to perform an Ajax Request to server and fill the missing values for the columns.

At first, the tree is displayed collapsed, so I was thinking on add a listener for a **"beforeexpand"** event, and perform an ajax call there and just, as soon as I get the data write it to the "001" attributes and reload the grid.

I already retrieve the data from server, that is not a problem, the problem is how can I add the missing values to that existing treestore which is being already being used by my tree grid panel.

I was looking for some information and I saw something related to NodeInterface class and use the "decoration" method, but I am not familiar with this ExtJS framework yet.

Does somebody know about how can I perform this? I will really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieved this a few weeks ago, but I post the solution if somebody needs to know about this. Since I am refreshing data of the tree and setting some new elements, I needed to use the "grid.reconfigure()" method. After loading the additional data, I used the "reconfigure" method without sending parameters and it worked as desired. Hope it helped. Regards.